# Play animation one after other

Tags: javascript, jquery

What i want to do is to play animation after another one in a loop with JQuery

```
for(i = 0; i < 25; i ++){
  $('#'+animations[i]).animate({...}, 1500);
}
```

The problem is that I don't want to use the callback inside the animate function because I have X animations to run and I can't "hardcode" theses. Javascript has no "wait" function. The delay() function is also not ideal.

Process : The animation 1 is running then finnished, then the animation 2 is running, finnished then animation 3 etc... But I have a dynamic array of animations.

The setTimeout method is a big problem because Javascript executes setTimeout and continues his execution.

```
for(i = 0; i < 25; i ++){
  setTimeout(function(){ $('#'+animations[i]).animate({...}, 1500); }, timer);
}
```

The value of var i will be 25 everytime because waiting the time to execute the anonymous function, the loop has finnished..

Comment: To make the value of "i" change, you have to wrap the setTimeout function into an IIFE, like this:

    `for(i = 0; i < 25; i ++){
      (setTimeout(function(j){ $('#'+animations[j]).animate({...}, 1500); }, timer))(i);
    }`

Comment: Adding on to @Mateusz's comment, instead of using an IIFE you could declare `i` using [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use recursive function calls, and call it again once the animation has completed, something like this

```js
function animate(start, end) {
  (function rec() {
    if (start <= end)
      $('#'+animations[start++]).animate({top:100}, 1500, rec);
  })();
}

/* setup  */
var animations = Array(25).fill(0).map( (_,i) => i);
animations.forEach( x => { $('<span />',{id:x}).appendTo('body') });
/* function call */
animate(0, 25);
```

```css
span {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background : red;
  display:inline-block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use callbacks for some reason, you can use your `i` and multiply it by time, so your code will be:

```
for(i = 0; i < 25; i ++){
  setTimeout(function(){ $('#'+animations[i]).animate({...}, 1500); }, i*1500);
}
```

This way you'll create timeouts all at once but they'll have delays set to 0, 1500, 3000, 4500 and so on.

Comment: This will not work because the time you're modifying is the duration, not the delay ;)

Comment: @MaartenBicknese edited my answer, this way it should work.